# TinyMCE adding "\n" as well as <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have just added tinyMCE in for a ticketing system I am writing. I am using the advanced theme and config pretty much directly from the examples.

My problem is that when I have multiple break's on the page, tinyMCE seems to be adding "\n" as well as the p tag.

How can I get it to not add the \n in?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried remove_linebreaks: true and that does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-tags are necessary for the styling of the text and other tasks. So every bit of text needs to be wrapped (in ps or divs). Concering the "\n"s: Can you give an example?

You might try the following setting: `apply_source_formatting : true`